# Injective? Surjective? Bijective? None? $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}, n \mapsto n^{2}-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Injective? Surjective? Bijective? None? $$f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow
> \mathbb{Z}, n \mapsto n^{2}-1$$

Because this is a quadratic function, we can be sure that it will be surjective. To be on the safe side, I have also let this function drawn:

[image]

So yeah it's surjective and it's not injective because we have quadratic function and if you take square root you will get +-, so 2 values you will get and this doesn't fulfill definition of injectivity. We can also see this from the graph.

Please tell me did I do it right?

Comment: It's because it's quadratic, you can be sure that it's **not** surjective.

Comment: It is not surjective, what $x$ maps to -2?

Comment: Why I get massive down votes on my questions? I at least provided all my thoughts, not trying to do my homework or something.-

Comment: Since its quadratic, you can be sure that its both not surjective, and not injective.

Comment: For similar questions see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033093/invert-this-function-g-mathbbn-rightarrow-mathbbn-n-mapsto-2n3-1), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032802/is-this-function-injective-or-surjective-g-mathbbn-rightarrow-mathbbn).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make an assumption that it is surjective because it is second degree polynomial and drawing the function we can see it is NOT surjective. Solve

$$-2=n^2-1$$

However we know right of the bat that quadratics are not surjective. We also know that they are not injective because $x^2=(-x)^2$ with $x\neq 0$ it is not injective.

Comment: Thank you for help but can you delete your answer so I can delete my question? Obviously my question is too stupid to be asked here. Although I don't understand it. I kinda feel discriminated.

Comment: Did the answer not help you?